# Can't update from v2.6.2789 via manual update

Tags: updating, manual-updates

I can't seem to update my local dev site Craft version (2.6.2789) to the latest 2.6.2964. I've followed the steps to update manually but it has no effect and still shows the v2.6.2789 in the footer.

Is there anything I can do to update?

Answer (score 2):

Are you 100% sure you are updating the right website/folder and not looking at the wrong one? Are you sure you are using the newest version of craft to install and not your old download?

If this is not the case. You could save your **templates** folder, **All the folders you made yourself in the public folder** and the **plugins** folder if you have any installed and make a backup of your current database and install a new fresh version of craft.

Then implement your saved files / database. Your database should be imported via the program or client you made your database in as this is not possible yet to do via the Craft admin panel. This is basically the same as a manual update.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the help. I'm pretty sure I updated the right folders, as I committed the changes with Git and the live version of the site is now running the latest version of Craft.

I'll give your other method a go. Thanks again.